# How to Check all PHP explode for string

Tags: php

I have exploded a text file using php. My objective is to check each string against a value, and if that value exists in the "exploded string" then reassign the value:

Value I am checking for: **"AM,B,L,PM"**
Objective: Convert all exploded strings of "**AM,B,L,PM**" to this **"AM,B,L"**

Pseudo Logic:

```
if ($pieces[2] = "AM,B,L,PM")
{
  $pieces[2] = "AM,B,L"
}
```

The above code works for a single **$pieces[2]**, but I want to check all $pieces, **$pieces[3], $pieces[4], $pieces[5]**

Please advise

Comment: Does a FOR loop ring any bells?

Comment: @RiggsFolly dumb question, but could you show me how

Comment: Yea. There is this ___very very secret place you can look these things up___ [Its called the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) ___Ssshhhhhh dont tell anybody about it___

Comment: too many questions, none accepted

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have received a lot of help here. I will close the questions properly - thank you

Comment: You might like to look back at some of your older questions and see if any of those answers are worthy of accepting. If thats allowed this late in the day ___Remember, you get REP for accepting a good answer___

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$l = count($pieces);

for($x=0;$l<$x;$x++) {

    if ($pieces[$x] == "AM,B,L,PM") {
        $pieces[$x] = "AM,B,L";
    }

}
```

or

```
$l = count($pieces);

for($x=0;$l<$x;$x++) {

    $a = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $pieces[$x]);

    if ($a == "AMBLPM") {
        $pieces[$x] = "AM,B,L";
    }

}
```

Comment: A good answer contains an _explanation_, not just "try this" (which doesn't help the OP understand what's going on).

Comment: You have to have 2 `==` in the `if` (comparing) and one `=` when you set the value. Now you're actually not setting anything.

Comment: A bit of sensible code indentation would make your code much more readable and understandable and maintainable

Comment: Subi I am trying your code; however, when I do: echo $pieces[370] // Output: "AM,B,L,PM"

Comment: Sry Bro, I don't Know why, But maybe a chance to some special charector in your string, so try this  $a = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $pieces[$x]); if ($a == "AMBLPM") {
        $pieces[$x] = "AM,B,L";
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could loop your array with a `foreach`, and if your condition is `true`, assign a value to the original array, and finally transform your array in a `string` again.

```
foreach ($pieces as $key => $piece) {
    if (trim($piece) == "AM,B,L,PM") {
      $pieces[$key] = "AM,B,L";
    }
}

// In the first parameter you put the delimiter you used to explode the string 
$string = implode(' ', $pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

$string = str_replace('AM,B,L,PM', 'AM,B,L', $pieces);

echo $string[370];

Solved. Thank you everyone